# Protecting a Hyperlink in android

Tags: android

I have an android application in which i have a hyperlink which opens in a browser.Its Right that Hyperlink on visible when any one enter right password otherwise it remain invisible.Problem is that if any one view the hyperlink by entering a correct password in browser then he will never need to again open the android app to open the hyperlink,So finally i want that user have to open the android app every time when he wants to view the page behind hyperlink. Here is My code through which i am making a hyperlink.

```
Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        txtDash=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDash);
        String linkText = "Visit the <a href='http://sml.com.pk/a/cms/cmsdbandroid.php'>CMS Dashboard</a> web page.";
        txtDash.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkText));
        txtDash.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                try {
                if (Password.getText().toString().equals("dsml"))
                {

                    txtDash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "invalid password - try again",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }catch(Exception e){
                     //Log.e("log_tag", "Error"+e.toString());
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Please Any One Help me to do this

Comment: Instead of only password protecting the *act* of going to a url that is, for all intents and purposes, public, you should password protect the URL itself and use your software to send the credentials to the website using a secure connection over SSL. I'm not an android expert, so I cannot help you with specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then opening the browser you can launch the URL in web view. URL would not be visible to the user in the web view. Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) for web view details.

Comment: Though with a proxy set up, it'll be very easy to find out anyway. I'd say the design is fundamentally flawed to begin with.

Comment: yah agree.. But I think most of the user would not bother to try to find the URL...

Comment: @J. Steen will u please elaborate your idea in detail

Comment: Simply because it *is* password "protected", I think a few users will be very determined to find out how to get in. It's in the very nature of bad security.